# Rewrite and redirect dynamic url with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Ok so my website has a dynamic url like this

```
web.com/?city=London
```

I want to change it to

```
web.com/London
```

While I found the code for rewrite i'm struggling to find one that changes and immediatly redirects people to url in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(.*)&)city=([^&]+)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(index.php)?$ %2?%1%3 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpe?g?|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteRule ([^/]+) index.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- The first part is responsible for rewriting the original URLs to the "pretty" format and redirect the browser to it
- Note that the first part only actually rewrites empty uri and "index.php" (assuming thats your directory index file).
- The second part, rewrites the request "back" to `index.php?city=London`, and then serves the newly created request by a sub-request (hiding the real url from the browser).

However, note that this results in an unnecessary redirects of the browser, so instead of relying heavily on part 1 of this scenario, you should consider reconstructing the urls within the server-side application, so they will appear in the "correct" form to begin with.

Comment: @MadRabbit updated the code with a fix. The problem was in detection of internal redirect actually (`IS_SUBREQ` is a different thing, it's not set upon internal redirtects)

Comment: I also changed the second rule to exclude images/css/js from rewriting so that you can keep using static files ;)

Comment: Damn, not sure why but I just can't get this to work :/

Comment: (1) You may need to add `RewriteBase /base/uri` and (2) check that your apache configuration allows `.htaccess` in first place (check `AllowOverride` directive, if it's set to `None`, apache won't read the per-dir files at all)